# implement signalA in Android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

For several days I have been trying to implement SignalA in my Android-Project.

I've found out that I have to import the 3 Projects (parallel-basic-http-client, SignalA and SignalALongPolling) in Eclipse. After the import of parallel-basic-http-client, I have several errors. It seems that the origin of those errors is in the import statement:

```
import com.turbomanage.httpclient.AsyncCallback;
```

In the console, the following statement is listed:

> [2013-12-03 09:03:45 - parallel-basic-http-client] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\Patrik\workspace\parallel-basic-http-client\bin\jarlist.cache

Below is the complete code for the understanding:

```
package com.zsoft.parallelhttpclient;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;

import com.turbomanage.httpclient.AsyncCallback;
import com.turbomanage.httpclient.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.turbomanage.httpclient.HttpRequest;
import com.turbomanage.httpclient.android.DoHttpRequestTask;

public class DoParallelHttpRequestTask extends DoHttpRequestTask {

public DoParallelHttpRequestTask(AsyncHttpClient httpClient,
        AsyncCallback callback) {
    super(httpClient, callback);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

 public void execute(HttpRequest httpRequest) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1) {
        super.execute(httpRequest);
    } else {
        super.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, httpRequest);
    }
}
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please fix the subject line

Comment: How can I fix the subject line? I'm new in Eclipse/Java.

Comment: grexter89 fixed it for you...I meant subject line of this post

Comment: sorry and thanks for the fixing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a problem with the dependencies used by SignalA.

To make it easier to use SignalA I've published it on Maven Central.